# Converted a field from nchar to nvarchar field, but still adds spaces on update

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldatatypes

I'm working in C# and I have a problem that I'm not sure how to solve.

I had a few fields that were nchar in sql server 2008, and noticed the spaces at the end, so I converted them to nvarchar in sql server.  Then for a test I edited them on the sql server side and removed the spaces.  It was just fine until I issue an update from my form, then it puts them all back.

I thought, I must have spaces on my side so I trim the field before writing, and even display it with `"*" + field + "*"` in a messagebox just to be sure, and there are no spaces.  The second I do the update, they are back.

I assume this is a problem with the dataset, but they are all just set as string.
So how do I get rid of the spaces?  I've tried trimming everything, and it makes no difference.

Do I have to destroy the table in the dataset and recreate it?  I wouldn't think I'd have to do anything except change it on the sql server side.

Just a note, I realize that just converting the field will leave the spaces, but I've already trimmed them from the data.  This is happening on the application side.

Comment: `nchar` doesn't pad your string with spaces. The datatype is not the issue. Can you show your updating code, please?

Comment: Actually I've found nchar does indeed pad with spaces.  After changing to nvarchar, a mass update using RTRIM would clean the data.

Comment: However, the problem still seems to be in the form update.. is it possible the form calls a stored proc that still declares nchar somewhere?

Comment: Can you please show the code where you declare the parameters and send the DML commands to SQL Server? Are you using parameterized statements? Are they still declaring the variables as nchar?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using parameterised SQL (for inserts and updates)?

Is your SQL parameter type an `nvarchar`?